# Barracuda v180 SSL VPN: What is the quick, efficient client connection workflow?

Tags: vpn, barracuda

This is a new device (within a year), with current firmware etc.

We are finding the client workflow to be cludgy. First the user has to start the vpn agent (desktop app). Then the login is done through a browser. Then the user goes BACK to the desktop app to start the tunnel.

Our users are.... not happy. (The old system gave single UI for signon, and once signed on the vpn just started.)

There seems to be more than one path to connect. (One of the paths uses browser to java integration -- another non starter.... java is fine, but not browser to java which requires settings, and breaks on browser/java updates.)

What is the "single path to happiness?"

- within the barracuda client tools
- via an alternate vpn client
- ?

(We use active directory integration + google authenticator for multi factor.)

Comment: Wouldn't this be a question to ask Barracuda support?

Comment: I noticed you cross posted this question on the Barracuda Forums too, which is probably the best place to ask. I shall be answering your question on there very shortly:
https://community.barracudanetworks.com/forums.php?url=/topic/26315-barracuda-v180-ssl-vpn-what-is-the-quick-efficient-client-connection-workflow/

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: There is no answer.

The process for sign in / vpn startup requires a web site and a desktop app, in a specific sequence, and is a real kludge.

It works, but it is not elegant.